# NASM Square brackets around directives like [BITS 16]?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have seen a lot of people writing

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]
```

While others write

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00
```

Does this make any difference in NASM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have read the documentation.

> NASM's directives come in two types: user-level directives and
>   primitive directives. Typically, each directive has a user-level form
>   and a primitive form. In almost all cases, we recommend that users use
>   the user-level forms of the directives, which are implemented as
>   macros which call the primitive forms.
>
> Primitive directives are enclosed in square brackets; user-level
>   directives are not.

> The BITS directive has an exactly equivalent primitive form, [BITS
>   16], [BITS 32] and [BITS 64]. The user-level form is a macro which has
>   no function other than to call the primitive form.

Comment: Not all documentation is very approachable or helpful.  The NASM documentation is generally excellent, though.   On this point, however, a quick read of the directive section does not answer: "why?"  Why are there both user-level and primitive directives?   Why the recommendation for using the user-level ones?   What's the point of having user-level directives that exactly match the primitive-level?   There are some user-level that do have behavior beyond just calling the primitive form.  Knowing this may be important.   So, yes, it *can* make a difference, depending on the directive.